# Taking a home screenshot and using it as background of your app

Tags: ios, background, screenshot, transparent, homescreen

I want to fake a transparent background in my app, so I thought the best way would be to take a screenshot of the home and use it as background.

The only problem comes with the fact that you can't possibly have the app take a screenshot without actually launching the app, so my question would be:

Is there any way to tell my app to take a screenshot of the home?

Comment: Ask the user to do it for you or jailbreak.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to rethink your design.  You cannot do this without jailbreaking.  It would also be very hard to maintain to ensure its up-to-date, and the user would see right past it. In addition, its highly unlikely an app with this method would pass through the review process.